# Display JSON data in jsp and html respectively

Tags: html, json, jsp

I'm a newbie to Java. My test.json file is an array that starts in the following format:

```
{
    "Result": "OK",
    "TotalRecordCount": 23,
    "Records": [{
        "vEmail": "blabla@gmail1.com",
        "vUserName": "admin",
        "nDepartmentId": "6750",
        "nEnabled": "1",
        "department": 6750,
        "vFatherName": "mixalis",
        "vSurname": "mixalis",
        "vAfm": "123456",
        "vUsertype": "",
        "vName": "mixalis",
        "nId": "5651",
        "rolesDesc": ""
    },
```

and so on...

I cant understand what the jsp and the html can do... i mean in this matter (i want to display the data by reading the json file)both can have the same result right? and same code right? ... ok this can be done with the following code in my jsp or my html page.. like that in the body section ? or in the head cause i m confused and dont know were goes were.... i have the simple page

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Loading JSON files using jQuery</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1 id="title"></h1>
<ul id="list"></ul>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $.getJSON("test.json", function(json){
            $("#email").text(json.vEmail);
            $.each(json.vUserName, function(key, val) {
                $("<li><a href='http://" + val + "'>" + val +    "</a></li>").appendTo("#list");
            }); // each()
        }); // .getJSON()
    }); // ready()
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You will notice that for testing purposes I haven't written all the data, only `vEmail` and `vUserName` but when I run it in Netbeans nothing showed up.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Try to write with correct spelling and grammar as much as possible, as your post will look better that way. Anyway, I can't find any HTML element with the ID `email`. Are you missing something? I also can't see anything related to Java or JSP in your question.

Comment: Yeas u r right , now i m working on html using the java framework jquery with the $.getJSON, later on i will start working with the jsp... i want to learn it first so i want to do it with both ways..that is html using jquery and later on with jsp.. so first thing first with html

Comment: ok in html using the getJSON a 1st approach according to my test.json above and here is my code a 1st approach..

Comment: and is working nice,, thank you so much  Qantas 94 Heavy and http://stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <html>
 <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
 <script>
  $(function() {
  var people = [];
   $.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {
     $.each(data.records, function(i, f) {
       var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.vEmail + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.vUserName +  "</td>" + "<td>" + f.nDepartmentId + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.nEnabled + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.department + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.vFatherName + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.vSurname + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.vAfm + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.vUsertype + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.vName + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.nId + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.rolesDesc + "</td>" + "</tr>"
       $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
    });
   });
  });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="wrapper">
 <div class="profile">
 <table id= "userdata" border="2">
 <thead>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>User Name</th>
        <th>Department Id</th>
        <th>Enabled</th>
        <th>Department</th>
        <th>Father Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Afm</th>
        <th>User Type</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Roles Desc</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
   </table>
 </div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

how to display json data in jsp page using spring?

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "58d2280914fe0a6e07b7469f"
    },
    "title": "test",
    "sms": "Testing By arun",
    "content": "Testing By arun",**strong text**
    "source": "",
    "contenturl": "",
    "videolink": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=94BzBOpv42g",
    "images": ["http://localhost:8088/src_bsnlcms/1490167809719_1490167813678.png"],
    "imagestxt": ["Testing By Raj"],
    "services": ["1~1~1"],
    "tag": [],
    "starred": 0,
    "ctype": 3,
    "author": "arun",
    "content_id": 1490167809719,
    "createdate": 1490167809719
}
```

Comment: Use [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to format your code