# how to get view data in JSON format from database using jsp

Tags: java, json, jsp

I want to change the view from the HTML list to JSON data.

This my code in controller:-

```
private void listFeedback(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws SQLException, IOException, ServletException {
        Feedback p = new Feedback();
        int seller_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("seller_id"));
        List<Feedback> feedbacks = p.all(seller_id);
        String format = request.getParameter("format");
        if(format == "json"){
            String json = new Gson().toJson(feedbacks);

            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            response.getWriter().write(json);
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("feedbacks/demo.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }
        request.setAttribute("feedbacks", feedbacks);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("feedbacks/list.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
```

But, It can be still viewed like before, nothing got to change at all. I wish it to be redirected to demo.jsp so that it can have a JSON view. Would anyone help me doing the same?

**UPDATE**

I just forget to put else in there
so, this the right code

```
else{
    request.setAttribute("feedbacks", feedbacks);
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("feedbacks/list.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

Thank you so much for answering my question.

Comment: are you sure the code present inside `if` executed?

Comment: Just write the `json` to `writer` and you do not need to forward the `request`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display JSON data in jsp and html respectively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398093/display-json-data-in-jsp-and-html-respectively)

Comment: @Kyera Nuna This [https://hibare.in/pageInfo.php?PageID=28] will definitely help you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks `format` value is null or not `json`. If the code present inside `if` executed, you would end up having error (The next lines of code, you are forwarding to another jsp).

> "Cannot forward after response has been committed"

Make the below changes to make it work:

you would not need to forward while you wanted to return the JSON. just add below code inside if

```
if("json".equals(format)){
                String json = new Gson().toJson(feedbacks);
                response.setContentType("application/json");
                response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                response.getWriter().write(json);
                return; // return from here or change to if-else
}
```

*The whole code:*

```
    private void listFeedback(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws SQLException, IOException, ServletException {
            Feedback p = new Feedback();
            int seller_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("seller_id"));
            List<Feedback> feedbacks = p.all(seller_id);


      String format = request.getParameter("format");
        if("json".equals(format)){
            String json = new Gson().toJson(feedbacks);
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            response.getWriter().write(json);
            return;// return from here or change to if-else
        }
        request.setAttribute("feedbacks", feedbacks);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("feedbacks/list.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
```